# Find the probability that a match will occur

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

**Anne, Joe, and Lynn, in this order, will take turns to draw two cards from a standard deck of 52 cards. Note that each draw of 2 cards is without replacement, but draws of different turns are with replacement (the precedent two cards will be put back and the deck will be reshuffled).**

**If two cards are in the same suite (e.g. two clubs), we call it a "match".**

**a) If each of them will have four turns, find the probability that all together more than three matches will be observed.**

**b) If they will take turns until a match is observed, find the probability that the drawing will end with Lynn.**

**c) If they will take turns until a match is observed, find the probability that the drawing with end with Lynn given that it does not end with Anne.**

*What I have tried so far:*

a) Here I let x = # of matches. I figured the probability of a match was $(4C1)\left(\frac{13}{52}\right)\left(\frac{12}{51}\right) = 4*\left(\frac{1}{17}\right) = \left(\frac{4}{17}\right)$ since there are 52 cards and 4 suites with 13 cards in each suite. Then there are 3 people, each of which get 4 turns, so overall there are 12 trials. This to me seems that it would follow a binomial distribution. So X~B(12, $\left(\frac{4}{17}\right)$). From here, if I have set this up right, calculating the probability should be trivial. I'm looking for:

$P(X \gt 3) = 1- P(X \le 3) = 1 - binomcdf(12, \left(\frac{4}{17}\right), 3) \approx 0.3062199228$

b) This one I have had more problems getting started with. Here, I let X = # of trials until a match is observed. Again, the probability of a match should be the same as part a, so P(X) = $\left(\frac{4}{17}\right)$. However, since Lynn is the third player in the game, here I seem to be looking for:

$P(X = 3n)$ where $y = 3n$ and $n = 0, 1, 2...$, and X~$Geo(\left(\frac{4}{17}\right))$. At this point I'm pretty uncertain how to proceed, but I just tried to plug things in by definition. So:

$P(X = 3n) = (1 - P)^{3n - 1}P = (\left(\frac{13}{17}\right)^{3n - 1}\left(\frac{4}{17}\right))$ where $n = 0, 1, 2...$

So here, I'm still a bit lost, but decided to try and turn this into a summation:

$\sum_{y=0}^\infty (1-p)^{(3n-1)}p = \sum_{y=0}^\infty \left(\frac{13}{17}\right)^{(3n-1)}\left(\frac{4}{17}\right) \approx 0.5565877$

So that's what I ended up with, but I'm fairly unconfident in this answer.

Part c seems similar, but it also seems to branch of off part b. So I haven't started it yet, since I feel I would be wasting time if I don't understand part b yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I have understood the rules correctly, in part $c$ Anne drops out of the question.  We know she never gets a match so forget her.  Therefore this is now just a two person game with Joe starting.  Much simpler.

Comment: Note:  to me, the card stuff just confuses the issue.  This is all easier to picture with a biased coin.  As the probability of a match is $\frac {12}{51}$ just describe the game as if our players were tossing a loaded coin which comes up $H$ with that probability.  Note:  if this is not the same game as yours, then I have misunderstood the rules (certainly possible).

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense for part c. I'll give that a try and see what I can come up with. Also, thinking of it in terms of a biased coin seems to make sense to me. It also would give me the same calculations in my parts a and b, I believe. Thank you for the help!